# List of lists filled with elements/rows of a list subtracted from one another

Tags: python, list, scipy, broadcast, subtraction

So I have a **`Nx1`** list, where each row **`(i->I)`** should be subtracted from all other elements forming a list, this list should then be part of another list which contains **`I`** rows. Currently I have been doing this with a loop, but was wondering if it would be possible with broadcasting to remove the requirement for loops, kind of like how pdist/cdist in scipy work.

For Example:

```
An input matrix of: [1,2,4,7,9] 
should result in: [[0,1,3,6,8],[-1,0,2,5,7],[-3,-2,0,3,5],[-6,-5,-3,0,2],[-8,-7,-5,-2]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly nicer ways to write it with `numpy`, but this is a way to do it:

import numpy as np

```
input = [1,2,4,7,9]

m = np.array(input * len(input)).reshape(len(input), len(input))
m - np.array(input).reshape(len(input), 1)

# array([[ 0,  1,  3,  6,  8],
#        [-1,  0,  2,  5,  7],
#        [-3, -2,  0,  3,  5],
#        [-6, -5, -3,  0,  2],
#        [-8, -7, -5, -2,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is a `numpy.array`, then the simplest solution is using `numpy.newaxis`:

```
>>> a=numpy.array([1,2,4,7,9])
>>> a-a[:,numpy.newaxis]
array([[ 0,  1,  3,  6,  8],
       [-1,  0,  2,  5,  7],
       [-3, -2,  0,  3,  5],
       [-6, -5, -3,  0,  2],
       [-8, -7, -5, -2,  0]])
```